# Return data from native method via pointer in .NET

Tags: c#, c++, api, type-conversion

The function I'm calling is part of an obscure API that cannot be PInvoked because the library's only entry point is a structure of pointers to the functions within. That being said, I have the structure and C++ implementation sample code.

> tl;dr I'm not PInvoking this function.

Here is what the implementation looks like in C++

```cpp
// Definition
extern  "C"  typedef short  (* GETBIT)(short,char*);

// Base function for using API
void anApi::GetData(short index, void* pData)
{
    switch(internal logic...)
    {
        case bitData:
            get_bit(index, (char *)(pData));

        case (other data types)...
    }
}

// Higher level API implementation
UCHAR u1Val = 0;
GetData( 1234, &u1Val );

if( u1Val == 1 )
{
    doSomthing();
}
```

Presumably I should get back either 0 or 1 (even with the actual data type being what it is). I should mention that the API has error checking, which I left out for simplicity sake, and my code does not cause any error. There is also an initialization function which succeeds, so I know I'm calling the functions correctly.

Here is how I've implemented the same function in C#

```c#
// Definition
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate short get_bit_delegate(short index, out byte data);
get_bit_delegate get_bit; 

// Base function
public string GetDataBit(short index)
{
    string ReturnData = "test";       
    // Using .NET type of Byte instead of char...
    byte myByte = 0;              
    lRetCode = get_bit(index, out myByte);
    // get a good look at what we returned
    ReturnData = Convert.ToString(myByte, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
    return ReturnData;
    // error checking snipped for brevity 
}

// Implementation
 textBox1.Text = GetDataBit(1234);
```

I've tried different data types including IntPtr and then Marshaling, but I keep getting the same result:

> 11111111 ( ÿ )

The way they use the result in the sample code, I would think that the return value should be '1' or '0'. In fact, in my test case I'm expecting to see 0.

0 - chr(48) - 00110000
1 - chr(49) - 00110001

Comment: what is `get_bit()` and why are you showing us the definition of `GETBIT`?

Comment: @MikeNakis In this case, get_bit() is a delegate to a function pointer (does not include any information about arguments) and GETBIT is the definition which does include that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all boils down to the contract of the function that you are trying to call, which you have not told us much about: Is it supposed to return a character, a byte, a bit, a boolean?

You should have expected `chr(48)` and `chr(49)` if the function you are calling was supposed to return a character.  But obviously, you are not receiving one.  Pay no attention to the fact that `char` is used internally: `char` is used in old-style C code in place of byte, bit and boolean.  So, you have to have some kind of spec to follow, instead of trying to do a literal reading of the internals of some other guy's code.

In the C family of languages, the `if()` statement checks whether something is zero (`FALSE`) or non-zero (`TRUE`).  As a result, when something is supposed to evaluate to `TRUE`, it is not necessary that it be equal to `1`, it can be any non-zero value.  And actually, `-1` is not uncommon.

A bit pattern of all `1`s is a non-zero value, so if it is examined as a boolean, it corresponds to TRUE. (And in two's complement a bit pattern of all `1`s is actually `-1`.) So, it is quite possible that the function you are calling is supposed to return a boolean value, and you are in fact receiving a `TRUE`.

(Of course, in light of this, code like `if( u1Val == 1 )` is kind of weird, it ought to have been `if( u1Val != 0 )`, so there may be something fishy going on.)

Comment: This is what my documentation for the argument looks like: `argument: data,  Model: char *, I/O: out, Explanation: Bit type data (0 or 1) is acquired.`

Comment: Okay, since it says `bit type data (0 or 1)` and not `char type data ('0' or '1')` you should definitely not be expecting `chr(48) or chr(49)`. The only other thing that I can think of is that the documentation is wrong, and it is returning `0 or non-0` instead of `0 or 1`.

Comment: I'll to continue testing and update question when I've got more information. I was basically looking for a sanity check when it came to the C++ -> C# conversion since my level of C++ isn't very high at the moment. From your response and the lack of any others, it sounds like I haven't made any obvious errors.

Comment: I found my problem... I assumed that the data type for would be bit, but the data I was looking for was actually byte. Calling the correct function gets me the right data `Doh!` Thanks for looking over my pseudo-code though.